# EACCES: permission denied, open 'path' when referencing a pdf in Create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app

Trying to show a download link for a PDF inside Create-react-app and
getting error:

> EACCES: permission denied, open 'correct path' when trying to import or reference any PDFs in a nested component (public or local folder)

The local way:

```
import Pdf from './Pro.pdf'
const info  = props => (
 <div id="info">
  <a download="foo.pdf" href = {Pdf} target="_blank">download </a>
 </div
 )
export default info
```

The public folder way:

```
<a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/Pro.pdf'}
```

had a similar problem with reaching data.json inside the public folder, solved it by making a xhttp request and sending it to the nested components with props but it seems like an awful way of doing things.

It's a front end only project and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: Public folder and Src folder are two different worlds. Please check the file is in same folder or not in this case ?

Comment: Thank you for replying,
the file is in both but i would prefer it being in the component's folder(Src) if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still wondering i managed to solve the problem with sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder by giving the entire folder read/write permissions.